Failed to run and deploy ASP.NET Core 6 Web App with Azure Entra ID sign-in to Google Cloud Run
TL;DR version: I'm unable to run/deploy ASP.NET Core 6 web application with Azure AD sign-in to Google Cloud Run. Application redirects to http version instead of https.
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 web application and I'm trying to deploy it to Google Cloud Run. Most tutorials are basic web app, but in my case, I had multiple projects in the solution. I failed to do this in my existing project, so I created an example project called ComplexApp (inspired by https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/complexapp/README.md dotnet docker repo). There is nothing complex about the application, it only references a Core project from the web solution.

I followed these steps to build and run the app on Google Cloud Run:

Create a docker file for the project
Created a repository in Google Cloud Artifact registry
Used Google Cloud Build to build the Docker container with this command: gcloud builds submit --tag {region}-docker.pkg.dev/{projectId}/{repositoryName}/complex-app-image:tag1
Used Google Cloud run from Google Cloud website to deploy the container (Create new service -> Deploy from existing container image)

Everything is fine and I can access my test web application:

One important thing I didn't mention is, since I had many issues while running this app with Docker in Cloud Run, I read Cloud Run documentation (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-dotnet-service) and in the C# example, there was this code block recommended for running the app.
var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") ?? "8080";
var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}";

app.Run(url);

I didn't fully understand when I did this change, but it was in the example and it also references the Container runtime contract page and the description below (image) was pointing out 0.0.0.0 and port 8080.

Here comes the interesting part. I have to use Microsoft Entra ID (aka Azure AD) sign-in in this project. So the requirement is, only people from my organization can see the web application. So as the next step, I followed the official Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-web-app-dotnet-core-sign-in) to implement Azure AD sign in in the project.
The first issue I have is, if I use var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}"; (not https) in the Program.cs file, I get error on my local:

System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I kind of anticipated this because it was the http version and it probably didn't work with Redirect URI.
If I use var url = $"https://0.0.0.0:{port}"; (with https), everything is fine. I've entered 'https://localhost:8080' in a private windows in Chrome. App redirected me to my company Azure AD sign in page, I've entered my credentials and redirected to the app.

This works with https, because I've entered both https://localhost:8080/signin-oidc and https://0.0.0.0:8080/signin-oidc into Web Redirect URIs section of my App Registration in Azure.

Now, if I build an image and deploy this version to Google Cloud, I get this Cloud Build error:
The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information..

From the logs:
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "complex-app-aad-image-1" on port 8080. The instance was not started.

If I deploy with var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}"; (http version), Cloud Run succesfully deploys the project but when I click the link, I get this error:

The URL I click is already in the Redirect URI section of my App Registration:

I can't add http version of this URL, Azure portal doesn't allow me to do that. Besides, I want to leverage the default HTTPS certificate of Google Cloud Run from the link I access.
As I explained before, without the Azure AD sign in functionality, I was deploying the app with http version and Cloud Run was redirecting to https. How do I achieve this with Azure AD sign in?
Startup.cs file: https://gist.github.com/alpersilistre/090b5ac6e58d54e0fd189dd3e4018806
Dockerfile: https://gist.github.com/alpersilistre/64cc89cbb8e9f810492f8a59ab25accb

Drive-by comment and not a .NET dev. You're correct that your app container (to adhere to Cloud Run's contract) must listen on 0.0.0.0:{port} but this isn't the public endpoint of your app which is reverse-proxied to TLS on port 443 with either an auto- or custom domain name. The DNS name (against 443) should be the Web redirect URL that's defined within your Azure config you should add (preferably your own custom domain) but worst-case https://{your-app}-{cloud-run-hash}-{cloud-run-region-hash}.a.run.app/signin-oidc because that's how it reaches your app's OAuth endpoint.

Hi @DazWilkin, thank you for the comment. The url was actually already there as https://..../singin-oidc, but your comment encouraged me and gave me idea to research further about reverse-proxy on asp.net core with docker. I found this article, and it seems there was an issue about this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22572
I've managed to fix it with a workaround by using ForwardedHeaders (by using UseForwardedHeaders middleware) after digging more. Thank you again. I'll write an answer so people would benefit if they face with similar issue.

You will find many articles about X-FORWARDED-FOR and X-FORWARDED-PROTO. Very common configuration issue in the cloud and in data centers.

Posting as a community based on the comment of @AlperSilistre:

The url was actually already there as https://..../singin-oidc, but your comment encouraged me and gave me idea to research further about reverse-proxy on asp.net core with docker. I found this article, and it seems there was an issue about this: github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22572 I've managed to fix it with a workaround by using ForwardedHeaders (by using UseForwardedHeaders middleware) after digging more.

